# C# write a JSON file, unfortunately, it always writes only one thing into it

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to create a JSON file and describe it. The first picture shows how it looks. It should looks like the second picture. Therefore my programming code is wrong. Does anyone have a solution for this? Because when I start my code so it always writes only one, the other things he always overwrites.How do I make it like the second *(With the heading (dxfFiles, vipFile) and the structure)*?

Thank you for your answers

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an1G8.png)

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khy6n.png)

```
JObject j = null;
foreach (Detection v in listVIP)
{
    j = new JObject(
        new JProperty("Dateiname", v.m_sFilename),
        new JProperty("Objekt-ID", v.m_sObjectID),
        new JProperty("Unterordner", v.m_sSubfolder),
        new JProperty("Url-Download", v.m_sDownloadlink)
    );

    foreach (Detection d in listDXF)
    {
        j = new JObject(
          new JProperty("Dateiname", d.m_sFilename),
          new JProperty("Objekt-ID", d.m_sObjectID),
          new JProperty("Unterordner", d.m_sSubfolder),
          new JProperty("Url-Download", d.m_sDownloadlink)
        );
        j.Add("Dateiname", "");
    }
}
File.WriteAllText(
  (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\test.json"), j.ToString()
);
```

Comment: Each iteration of the loop, you ***overwrite*** `j` with a different `JObject`. Perhaps you should stick your `j`s in a `JArray` instead of chucking them out?

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and how do I add these "headings" (dfxFiles, vipFile)?

Comment: Please include your JSON data as text, not images

Comment: I improved the code formatting. Unfortunately I was unable to include the images as text/code sections, because this is beyond the scope of review. I'm gonna leave it to the author if he/she aspires to receive a valuable answer.

Comment: @zx485 
First time thank you. I've already received the answer I needed, so I did not make any changes. For the next time I know it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your desired JSON like this:

```
JArray jaVIP = new JArray();
foreach (Detection v in listVIP)
{
    jaVIP.Add(new JObject(
        new JProperty("Dateiname", v.m_sFilename),
        new JProperty("Objekt-ID", v.m_sObjectID),
        new JProperty("Unterordner", v.m_sSubfolder),
        new JProperty("Url-Download", v.m_sDownloadlink)));
}

JArray jaDFX = new JArray();
foreach (Detection d in listDXF)
{
    jaDFX.Add(new JObject(
        new JProperty("Dateiname", d.m_sFilename),
        new JProperty("Objekt-ID", d.m_sObjectID),
        new JProperty("Unterordner", d.m_sSubfolder),
        new JProperty("Url-Download", d.m_sDownloadlink)));
}

JObject j = new JObject(
    new JProperty("dxfFiles", jaDFX),
    new JProperty("vipFile", jaVIP));

File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + 
                  "\\test.json", j.ToString());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RHsKk0

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Sir!